# How to import a large number of files into SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, import, file-upload

I have 500 GB in .pdf and .doc files on my file share and I want to put all of those into SharePoint.

What is the best way to do it? I have a database size of 250 GB. I also want to be able to search and index. Do I need a bigger HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading 500GB of data into a 250GB database is going to be problematic for obvious reasons.

There are a number of [third party utilities](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+migrate+files) available to do this, but the most affordable way is to go to a Document Library and choose to open it in Windows Explorer. I would then recommend to move (not copy) files in batches to SharePoint for the following reasons:

- **Move**: you are going to get errors for all kind of reasons (e.g using forbidden characters such as '&' in file names. By moving files you don't have to recopy files that have succeeded previously.
- **Batches**: It is going to take a while. Copy 50GB at a time, or whatever amount works.

Regarding the ability to search through PDF files, you will need to [install a PDF iFilter](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=sharepoint+index+pdf+foxit&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). I recommend the one from Foxit as it is much faster than the Adobe one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to capture additional metadata besides the basic information like author and modified that already exists in windows, then the easiest way is to map a network drive to the SharePoint document libraries you want to store the documents in and then drag and drop them.

So if your document libraries are at

http://sharepoint/site/documentlibrary1/

http://sharepoint/site/documentlibrary2/

You would map the drives to

\sharepoint\site\documentLibrary1

\sharepoint\site\documentLibrary2

Once the shares are setup just drag and drop the files using Windows Explorer.

After that you can update metadata and other items using the UI as the documents are accessed during normal operations or through code in the object model.

You might also look at creating document links through the object model and leaving the files themselves on a file share.

Or if you don't need the document management features of SharePoint you can leave them on a file share and just surface them by indexing them in SharePoint search from Central Administration.